# Is there any reason to re-rack and wait another week after dry hopping before bottling?

Tags: bottling, dry-hop

Is there any reason to re-rack and wait another week after dry hopping before bottling? The only reason I can think of is for settling of residual dry hopped particulates. But if you don't syphon those out, is there any reason to wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in fact the rewards almost certainly don't outweigh the risk of oxygen pickup (or contamination) from the rack. This is especially the case if you're not going to be performing a true secondary fermentation (i.e. bottle- or keg-conditioning). Even if you are, best to rack straight into the bottle or keg so that any ill effects of oxygen pickup will be mitigated by immediate yeast action.

If you're worried about hop particles (or anything, really), just leave it where it is for another week. I can think of almost no case where it's better to rack *again* than it is to just leave the beer where it is a bit longer.

Comment: FWIW I just bottled this today, off the dry hop. My only problem was sucking up hops into the bottling bucket, which then clogged my bottling wand. Next time I'll rerack at least for a few days to get the hops out.

Comment: I think it would be better to put a filter on the end of your racking cane. I use a bit of plastic mesh for window screens, held in place by a bit of wire.

Comment: I use a fine nylon mesh bag over my racking cane/syphon. Works well.